# preg_replace not working how I expect

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to php and I'm having a problem with preg_replace.  I'm using php version 5.3.2 and I have this line of code:

```
$minYear = preg_replace("/(\s)|(now)/g", "", $minYear);
```

Before this line of code, `$minYear` has the string `now-6` in it.

After this line of code, `$minYear` is an empty string.  I'm expecting it to have `-6`

I've tried with and without the brackets in the regex pattern.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note: 5.3.2 is quite old. The entire 5.3 branch is eol. If you are not on debian or rhel (or another distro that still ships security upgrades) I'd strongly suggest upgrading.

Comment: Out of my control unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `g` flag in PHP regex as replacement is always global. You can also remove unnecessary grouping from your regex.

You can use:

```
$minYear = preg_replace('/\s|now/', "", $minYear); // -6
```